# How to exclude product in the order by different sellers in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, e-commerce

I'm trying to show orders that belong to a certain seller when a customer place an order. The problem comes when a customer buys multiple products at once from different sellers.The order(including other products in cart) goes to the seller whose product is last in cart.

if the order is only one product everything seems to work. Here is how my query looks like in controller.

```
 // Seller Orders 
 public function viewOrders(User $user)
 {

 $orders = Auth::user()->sellerOrders()->products()->with('seller')- >orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(2);
 // dd($orders);
 return view('orders')->with('orders', $orders);
 }
```

Here is my user.php

```
 public function sellerOrders()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Order::class, 'seller_id');
 }
```

Here is Order.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}

public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product')->withPivot('quantity');
}
```

this is what is in product model

```
protected $table='products';
protected $primaryKey='id';
protected $fillable=  ['seller_id','pro_name','pro_price','pro_info','image','stock','category_id'];
}

 public function seller()
{
// a product belongs to a seller
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}
```

Here is how my tables looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vExX.jpg
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your relationship between a product and a seller?

Comment: Also, do you have separate models for sellers and customers?

Comment: @party-ring a user can be either a seller or a buyer

Comment: I updated the question to include product model.

Comment: Okay so you need to make a function that will connect your products to its seller, does a product have the id of the user that is the seller?

Comment: Yeah, product table has seller_id @party-ring

Comment: Change `public function Order()` to `public function orders()` and `Auth::user()->orders()->...` because Order() also exists as the model class name Order. It won't solve the issue at hand but try to avoid possible confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Product.php

```
public function seller()
{
    // a product belongs to a seller
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'seller_id');
}
```

So you would have an `$order` and you can retrieve the order products like so:

`$order->products()->with('seller')->get();`

Using `->with('seller') will load in the sellers, and you use Eloquent's query builder`->groupBy('seller')` clause to group your results.

Comment: After changing everything I'm getting this error `"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::products()"` @part-ring

Comment: Please check all the updates in the question@part-ring